Separation of Integral
I have a question about the following derivation in a textbook about linear optical pulse propagation:
Background
For EM wave through a linear medium, the response in the time domain is described by the convolution of the impulse response and the EM wave:
$$E_{out}(t)=\int h(t')E_{in}(t-t')\,dt'=h(t)\ast E_{in}(t)$$
In the above equation, $h(t)$ is the impulse response:
$$h(t) = \int h(t')\delta (t-t')\,dt'$$
The Fourier transform of $E_{out}(t)$ is derived in the book as follow:
$$\begin{align}
E_{out}(\omega)&=F\left\{\int h(t')E_{in}(t-t')\,dt'\right\} \\
&=\iint h(t')E_{in}(t''-t')e^{-i\omega t''}\,dt'\,dt''\\
&=\iint h(t')E_{in}(t''-t')e^{-i\omega(t''-t')}e^{-i\omega t'}\,dt'\,dt''\\
&=\int h(t')e^{-i\omega t'}\,dt'\int E_{in}(t''')e^{-i\omega t'''}\,dt'''\\
&=F\{h(t)\}F\{E_{in}(t)\}\\
&=h(\omega)E_{in}(\omega)
  \end{align}$$
Question
My question is why the integration can be separated while $t'''=t''-t'$, $t'''$ contains $t'$, and thus cannot be separated like two independent variables in my opinion.
For example
$$f(x,y)=\iint x+y\,dx\,dy=\frac{x^2y+xy^2}{2}$$
Let $u=x+y$, if assuming $u$ and $x$ are independent as in the above derivation, then:
$$
f(x,y)'=\iint u\,dx\,du
=\frac{xu^2}{2}
=\frac{x^3+2x^2y+xy^2}{2}
\neq f(x,y)
$$
Intead it should have been:
$$
\begin{align}
f(x,y)''=\iint u\,dx\,(du-dx)&=\iint u \,dx\,du - \iint u\,dx\,dx\\
&=\frac{xu^2}{2}-\frac{ux^2}{2}\\
&=\frac{x^2y+xy^2}{2}\\
&=f(x,y)
\end{align}
$$
However, the conclusion $E_{out}(\omega)=h(\omega)E_{in}(\omega)$ seems intuitively correct to me, is my understanding on calculus wrong?

One thing that you should notice is that the Fourier transform is a definite integral. So the domain matters. When you integrate over $t'''$ you get a function of only $\omega$. So if you would integrate between $0$ and $1$ for both $x$ and $y$, you need to change the integration limits for $u$ from $x$ to $1+x$:
$$\int_0^1 dx\int_0^1 dy (x+y)=1$$$$\int_0^1 dx\int_{x}^{1+x} du u=\int_0^1\frac12\left((1+x)^2-x^2\right)dx\\=\frac12\int_0^1(1+2x)dx=1$$

Thanks for the suggestion Andrei.
Even when the integral is definite, the two integrations are not separated in your example. The integration of $u$ is integrated by the integration of $x$. In the book, the author separates the two integrations and integrate independently.

That's because the limits are $\pm\infty$. Therefore something like $-\infty+t'$ is just $-\infty$
